# Add multiple items to hashmap

Tags: java, android

i am busy with a program that needs to populate `edit texts` with a drop down from the database, I am using a hashmap but i need to put about 10 columns in the hashmap because there are 10 fields that needs to be populated.

Here is my code:

```
        try {
            ConnectionHelper conStr = new ConnectionHelper();
            connect = conStr.connectionclass();

            if (connect == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                String query = "select * from Customers";
                stmt = connect.prepareStatement(query);
                rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                ArrayList<String> dataF = new ArrayList<>();
                hashmap = new HashMap<>();


                while (rs.next()) {
                    String id = rs.getString("CUSTOMER_ID");
                    String CName = rs.getString("CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME");
                    String Surname = rs.getString("CUSTOMER_SURNAME");
                    String Number = rs.getString ("CUSTOMER_TEL_NUMBER");
                    String Cell= rs.getString ("CUSTOMER_CELL_NUMBER");
                    String Buiilding= rs.getString ("CUSTOMER_BUILDING_NUMBER");
                    String Street= rs.getString ("CUSTOMER_STREET");
                    String suburb= rs.getString ("CUSTOMER_SUBURB");
                    String City= rs.getString ("CUSTOMER_CITY");
                    String postal= rs.getString ("CUSTOMER_ZIP_CODE");
                    // value of database
                    dataF.add(id);
                    hashmap.put(id,CName,Surname,Number,Cell,Buiilding,Street,suburb,City,postal);

                }
                ArrayAdapter NoCoreAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dataF);
                customerselect.setAdapter(NoCoreAdapter);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   customerselect.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                       int position, long id) {
                String name = customerselect.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String CName = hashmap.get(name);
                String Surname = peopleByForename.get(name);
                String Number = hashMap1.get(name);
                String Cell = hashMap2.get(name);
                String Building = hashMap2.get(name);
                String Street = hashMap3.get(name);
                String suburb = hashMap3.get(name);
                String City = hashMap4.get(name);
                String postal = hashMap4.get(name);

                rFname.setText(CName);
                        rLname.setText(Surname);
                rTelnum.setText(Number);
                        rCellnum.setText(Cell);
                rCusbuild.setText(Building);
                        rCusstr.setText(Street);
                rCussub.setText(suburb);
                        rCuscity.setText(City);
                rCuszip.setText(postal);


            }
```

I get the following error:

```
put() in HashMap cannot be applied to:
Expected Actual
Parameters Arguments
Key: String id
value: String CName 
Surname(java.lang.string)
Number(java.lang.string)
Cell(java.lang.string)
Building(java.lang.string)
Street(java.lang.string)
suburb(java.lang.string)
City(java.lang.string)
postal(java.lang.string)
```

The reason i am using hashmap is because the example i followed used hashmaps and i have no idea how to use the list to display in the drop down

Comment: I think you need to use List instead of Map or you can explain why you exactly need to use HashMap  so this forum can help you..

Comment: @DhaRmvEErsiNgh i updated the question

Comment: Can you please show how you want to use this hash map.. If you want to access all these values based on a single key you can use Map<String, List<String>>..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HashMap` only takes two parameters: `key` and `value`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/HashMap.html

---

The `key` should be an identifier that is unique to your object. In your case, you are using `id`. If that is the primary key on your database table (or any other unique number), that is exactly correct.

The other fields need to be wrapped together into a single object (or else stored in the HashMap individually, each with their own unique id; based on your question, it doesn't look like that is what you are doing).

You should be doing something like this:

```
    final Customer customerObject = new Customer(CName, Surname, Number, Cell, Buiilding, Street, suburb, City, postal);
    hashmap.put(id, customerObject);
```

*Creating the custom `Customer` class and all its fields is left as an exercise for the reader.*

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source of the `put` method of the `Map` interface you will notice that you can only find:

`put(K key, V value)`

And this is exactly how a `Map` should work. You map a key to a value so you can quickly access it while not iterating over the whole map. So in your case, i recommend you store all information in a serperate object like `Customer` and map it to the related id of the customer.

If you need to query for customer data efficiently (while not using the id) think about using a database which can do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Hashmap can only contain two columns. < Key >< Value >
You can create a Customer class and add these values to a customer object. Then put that class into the Hashmap.

```
Hashmap<String,Customer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(id, new Customer(id,surname,number...));
```

Answer (score 0):

Put method is of `Map<K, V>.put(K key, V value)` signature. So you cannot just add values. First figure out what the key should be then use the put method. You can retrieve the value using the key by calling `Map.get(Object key)` method.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example i hope you understand how you use this example with your scenerio.

```
public class Person{
String name,surName,number,....;

 public String getName(){
  return name;
 }

 public void  setame(String name){
  this.name=name;
 }

 //Create more getters setters like this
}



// create our map
Map<String, List<Person>> peopleByForename = new HashMap<>();    

// populate it
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
people.add(new Person("Bob Smith"));
people.add(new Person("Bob Jones"));
peopleByForename.put("Bob", people);

// read from it
List<Person> bobs = peopleByForename["Bob"];
Person bob1 = bobs[0];
Person bob2 = bobs[1];
```

Comment: I updated the question, i followed your instructions, how would i read from it like the way i used it in the updated question

Answer (score 0):

i'd create Customer object which will contain all that fields, than just add that object to map like `hashmap.put(id, yourCustomerObject);`